# testflow fails when testing Openmdao

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to use openmdao.  I have followed the instructions on the openmdao website, but when I run testflow get messages telling me it has failed.  I am running Windows 10.  Are there any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

I get the following messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\testflo\discover.py", line 130, in _module_iter
    fname, mod = get_module(filename)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\testflo\util.py", line 320, in get_module
    __import__(modpath)
  File "C:\...\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-0.1-1-gf5522be\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-f5522be\src\test\test_Turbine_CostsSE.py", line 12, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\testflo\discover.py", line 130, in _module_iter
    fname, mod = get_module(filename)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\testflo\util.py", line 320, in get_module
    __import__(modpath)
  File "C:\... \NREL_programs\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-0.1-1-gf5522be\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-f5522be\src\test\test_Turbine_CostsSE_gradients.py", line 12, in <module>
    from commonse.utilities import check_gradient_unit_test
ImportError: No module named commonse.utilities

The following tests failed:
C:\...\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-0.1-1-gf5522be\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-f5522be\src\test\test_Turbine_CostsSE.py
C:\...\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-0.1-1-gf5522be\WISDEM-Turbine_CostsSE-f5522be\src\test\test_Turbine_CostsSE_gradients.py
```

Passed:  0
   Failed:  2
   Skipped: 0

Answer (score 1):

`ImportError: No module named numpy`

It looks like you haven't installed numpy. You'll also need scipy too.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have both numpy and scipy installed.  I installed anaconda.  I'm not sure why I am getting those messages.  A friend told me that the testflow test may be used with the Github version of openmdao.  I did not use the Gitflow version.  I installed openmdao using pip.  I am going to try to a different tutorial example and see if that works.

Comment: something has gone wrong with your anaconda installation. If you go into a python interpreter and type `import numpy` it likely doesn't work.

Comment: I downloaded Anaconda when I installed the IDE Spyder 2.3.6.  I do not have any problems using numpy and scipy within Spyder.  I have never tried running python from the command line.  Do you think I should remove Spyder and Anaconda and try reinstalling only Anaconda?

Comment: im not a spyder user, so im a bit out of my depth here. But I think something must be funky with your install. The error you're getting clearly shows that when running your openmdao script it can't find numpy. Are you running the script from inside spyder? Maybe there is some kind of bad interaction with spyder and your openmdao install. Something is definitely amis though.

Comment: Ignore my last message.  I opened the Anaconda command line and ran pip install openmdao and it was installed successfully and the paraboloid example works!!!!  Yea!!  Thank you for your help